# Error when running next js - TypeError: (0 , react_jsx_dev_runtime__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__.jsxDEV) is not a function

Tags: node.js, reactjs, next.js

I just created a next project, and when I start the server, I have this error, but without more information. I didn't find any solution :(

TypeError: (0 , react_jsx_dev_runtime__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__.jsxDEV) is not a function

[Reported error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kzK2T.png)

Comment: I've been observing this problem in node 14, but I seem only to be able to run into this in a docker container. When I run this locally, it works fine.

Comment: I am in windows, not in a docker, and still get the same bs error that nobody knows wtf even is. Swear to god with these frameworks it takes more time to get the project to run than to write the application you needed to write in the first place

Comment: did you find a solution?

Comment: actually i fixed the issue by starting my application with `export NODE_ENV=dev node server.js` command

Comment: if I want to set the node_env to production, is it possible to fixed this issue?@ggnoredo

Answer (score 32):

As @ggnoredo has said you only get the error when your "NODE_ENV" environment variable is set to "production". So on windows the error can be fixed by running `setx NODE_ENV development` and on linux and macos by running `export NODE_ENV=development`.

Comment: `export NODE_ENV="development"` fixed the issue I was having with blitz (which use next and webpack too) on linux (wsl)

Comment: Thanks, was stuck at the very first step otherwise

Comment: as @kiratot said please use `development` value for `NODE_ENV`, otherwise NextJS will complain that `dev` is a non-standard environment specification.

Comment: but I still need to set the node env to production.

Answer (score 0):

I was playing around with `NODE_ENV=test` because of some CI bugs before.

This worked for me: `rm -r .next && pnpm next build && pnpm next start`

Answer (score 0):

If you encounter this issue, it's important to ensure that your React file doesn't contain unnecessary () in the return JSX section. It seems its trying to resolve an empty block